# How do I set up a network bridge?

Tags: networking

I have a wireless connection through my laptop that I am attempting to bridge through an ethernet cable to my xbox. So far I have not found anything online that explains how to do this. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Reads very similar to a question posted on [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1340187).

Answer posted on that site which apparently worked;

> nevermind i solved it. all i had to do was go to network connections.
>   click "Auto eth0" in the "wired" tab. click "edit" go to "IPV4
>   settings" tab and choose "shared to other computers" in the "method"
>   pull down menu. then choose "available to all users" in the bottom
>   left and then apply. then back in the network connections main menu i
>   choosed the "wireless" tab clicked the "auto (whatever my routers name
>   is)" and clicked "edit" and then chose "available to all users" in the
>   bottom